# Cocos3D - Take various screenshots in the background

Tags: cocos3d

Using Cocos3D, is it possible to take screenshot of the 3D model in the background without the user knowing it?

For pre-processing purpose and other usage, I want to take screenshots of the 3D model at various angles. Following the Render-To-Texture capability, I noticed when my scene is not visible, the `drawSceneContentWithVisitor:` method only execute once rather than at every rendering cycle.  For obvious reason, the `CC3GLFramebuffer*` won't get updated with new data, hence, I'm only able to take the initial screenshot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In **Cocos3D**, you can render your 3D scene to an off-screen *surface*. See the `CC3DemoMashUp addTelevision` and `drawSceneContentWithVisitor:` methods for an example of how to do this.

What is important is that the 3D drawing environment has been established when you perform your drawing. The safest place to do this is inside your `drawSceneContentWithVisitor:` method. But if you want to render somewhere else, you need to invoke the `CC3Scene open3DWithVisitor:` and `CC3Scene close3DWithVisitor:` methods before and after rendering. See the implementations of the `CC3Scene processInitializeScene` and `open` methods for examples of how to do that.

To render your scene from multiple viewpoints, you need to add multiple cameras to your scene, and set the `camera` property of your drawing visitor appropriately to select a camera before rendering. See how this is done in the `CC3DemoMashUpScene addTelevision` and `drawToTVScreen` methods. The `drawToTVScreen` method also shows how to handle clearing the color and depth buffers of your surface.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't being very clear about my question, and you are correct, we can render the texture from multiple viewpoints using multiple cameras. What I'm really trying to do is render the animated 3D model over delta time rather than the static 3D model. I.e Over the period of 5 seconds, the 3D model may animate and x number of images would get captured. Since drawSceneContentWithVisitor: only executed once if running in the background, I'm unable to animate the 3D character.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create a series of animated snapshots...kind of like a flip-animation? And I guess you'd want to save the images to a dictionary or files? Have a look a the `CC3DemoMashUpScene saveTVImage` method. It creates a `CGImageRef` from the current contents of the TV texture (which is a rendered texture), and saves it to a file. The example is triggered by a touch event, but by performing it in your `drawSceneContentWithVisitor:` method (right after the texture rendering), you could take these snapshots as often as you like as your scene is animated.

Comment: Actually, animation is happening in the background for pre-processing purpose. Since it's in the background, drawSceneContentWithVisitor: method only execute ONCE, rather than at every render cycle.

Comment: Bill, how do I generate images with transparent background? I followed the `saveTVImage:` but my images background either has the original backdrop or BLACK color.

Comment: I read your other posts, but unfortunately, I don't have any special insight into extracting the transparency into a `CGImageRef` and PNG file. The challenge seems to be in setting the `CGImageRef` specifications in variations of the `createCGImageFrom:` and `saveTVImage` methods. You might find some more info on a general iOS image processing forum, or in Apple's image processing docs.

Comment: I was afraid you would say that. Do you think it's possible if I use cocos2D CCRenderTexture as alternative? There's a post here with a section that instruct how to capture screenshot but nothing was mentioned of transparency. http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/how-to-use-ccrendertexture-motion-blur-screenshots-drawing-sketches/

Comment: As a guess...I'd say I doubt that will help, because the texture rendering mechanisms are similar (but, never say never, if you want to give it a try!). As I mentioned, I think the issue is in how the `CGImageRef` is created and manipulated from the texture content.